# Make AzureServiceTokenProvider static in Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

For HTTP and DocumentDb clients, it is recommended to make them static in an Azure Functions.

Is it recommended to make an `AzureServiceTokenProvider` instance static in an Azure Function, instead of creating it every function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, HttpClient is notorious for implementing IDisposable and and encouraging `Using{}` blocks... and well... just not [handling it well](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). Too much instantiation can lead to socket exhaustion.  The static/singleton pattern is heavily encouraged.

But, I don't think `AzureServiceTokenProvider` has the same issues? So, you shouldn't need to follow those same patterns.  The token provider has a static caching method on the backend, that code is located here [AccessTokenCache.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/ddda7cb74b979f03bb03e240c06c924914ee8bdd/src/SdkCommon/AppAuthentication/Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/Cache/AccessTokenCache.cs). So, the cache should be shared across all instances.  So, when using it... no need to have static instance.